# Duration to min

Tags: php, template-lite

I make some search on Google and Stackoverflow but does not reach anything

I use template lite and retrieve movie durations via it. In my db, the durations are like that

```
0215
0310
```

Is there a way in template lite or php to show them in mins ?

ex:

0215 = 135

Comment: `0310 - 0215` perhaps? Obviously you replace them with the variables containing data, but the preceding `0`s should be stripped off, or can be by casting both variables to an `(int)`.

Comment: Ah. What wasn't immediately obvious to me about the this question is that the data is in 'hhmm' (PHP `date('Hi')`) and it should be converted to minutes.

Comment: For the sake of normalization I would convert the column that stores this obscure `hhmm` format to store the duration in minutes (or seconds if needed) instead. This will spare you much trouble when doing anything with the duration other than outputting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$duration = "0215";
$mins = substr($duration,0,2)*60+substr($duration,2);
```

Simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
function toMinutes($duration) {
  return ltrim(substr($duration, 0, 2), '0') * 60 
           + ltrim(substr($duration, 2), '0');
}
```

The trimming is to avoid the string being cast to an octal instead of an integer, just in case.